# How to assign the ' Web Browser Shortcut' to Synapse?

Tags: shortcut-keys, synapse

My laptop has three extra keys, For Opening Mail client, Web browser and one other.
I dont use them, so I want to assign the the web browser key to open [synapse](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/11/syanpse-is-here-new-semantic-launcher.html), currently I use Super+Space to open Synapse but now that I don't use the extra key given to open the web browser, I want to assign that key to open synapse, Is it possible?

I looked into the 'keyboard shortcuts' and saw that `XF86WWW` was written as shortcut next to `Launch Web Browser`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must be crazy to not try this before asking this question. So, here are the obvious steps...

first go to keyboard shortcuts and change the XF86WWW to something else so that it doesn't conflict with the synapse shortcut. 
Go to synapse preferences and click on shortcut and then just press the web browser hotkey and it will be enabled to trigger synapse.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have these keys so I can't try it. You can try to remove this shortcuts ("Launch Web Browser") and add a new shortcuts with key `XF86WWW` and command **synapse**.

Or remove the shortcut for "Launch Web Browser" and use `XF86WWW` in Synapse.